# How to rotate the local axis of an applied (weight-painted) bone without moving the mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

i want the local rotation axis of the bone to align with the mesh but its already applied and i dont want to re-weightpaint everything again. thank you

[image: i want the local rotation axis of the bone to align with the mesh]

Comment: Make the change in edit mode.  If you want to change the Y axis, change the bone's roll on sidebar or use a recalculate roll operation.  Beware of the how this may affect whatever constraints the bone has.

Comment: thank u that worked !